# CakePhp2 defined CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH, now DS and CORE_PATH undefined in ShellDispatcher

Tags: shell, cakephp, console, cakephp-2.2

In order to share CakePhp2 core between many sites I edited CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in webroot/index.php to point to the cake directory.  That works and I can reach my welcome page.

However, when I attempted to run the Cake Console, I ran into issues with ShellDispatcher.php not defining DS and CORE_PATH because they were only defined if CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH was NOT defined.  Once I defined them out of the if statement which checks if CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH was not defined, I was good to go.  However, I would prefer not to "hack" this file because I want to keep the cake core files clean.  Are there any better and cleaner options?

I also had to defined CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH and use it to set $dispatcher in Console/cake.php which is part of the app of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are. As a start never define application-wide variables in `Webroot/index.php`. As a matter of fact you shouldn't be touching this file at all. You can define variables in 
`Config/bootstrap.php`.

You were getting the error because when in a Shell you're not firing `Webroot/index.php` at all - you're actually running [PHP's CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) and CakePHP fires off in a different manner.
It will go through the `bootstrap.php` file of course.

You should also use this file to define any global vars, but there is a little bottleneck
here when using [PHP's $_SERVER variable's](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) web server related members - e.g. HTTP_HOST and the definition: `$myHost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`. If you start a shell Cake will try to set this variable and it will fail throwing an error. This is because as mentioned before PHP will be running in CLI mode when the CakeShell is envoked. There is a way to detect this of course - you can use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] or $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] in `bootstrap.php` to identify if you're in CLI or not. :)

Comment: It was my intention to add standard controllers/views to this app so it has a webapp portion. In that case, isn't it accepted to edit Webroot/inde.php? Can I do both and still separate Cake core from my apps?

Comment: No. `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` is a configuration value and that's what the `Config` dir is for. `Webroot/index.php` is the "The Front Controller for handling every request". Using the files under `Config` is cleaner. You can create a `shell.php` file in `Config` and load it in `bootstrap.php` only if under shell if that is even cleaner for you.

Comment: Is Config/bootstrap.php automatically loaded when core is in a different place than the default setup?  I ask because as a test I put a die statement at the top of it and I don't seem to be reaching it.

Comment: `Config/bootstrap.php` is in `app/` so yes it should be automatically loaded. All [CakePHP requests](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/a-typical-cakephp-request.html) go through it.

Comment: As said before you should use `bootstrap.php` and `core.php`. I prefer separating application specific configuration from core configuration via these two files - app specific stuff goes into `bootstrap.php`, Cake core configurations - in `core.php`. Both will run every time when a request is made or the all is launched in CLI mode.

Comment: Improved, but not ideal. ShellDispatcher.php  is no longer hacked. I still had to edit Webroot/index.php `ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'cakephp-2.2.0' . DS .'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));` adding the folder name where my Cake files live. Next in Console/cake I defined the full path for $dispatcher versus just `'Cake' . $ds . 'Console' . $ds . 'ShellDispatcher.php'` which could not be reached. I now reach my web welcome page and can execute `Console/cake`. I would still like to follow your approach, but defining the vars in core or bootstrap is not working.

Comment: This is very strange and it should work. You will have to check with our setup as this should be working "out of the box". Cheers.

Comment: I have been checking my out of the box install all along and it's fine. Also, I know I'm reaching `Config/bootstrap.php` on the web install because I can put die statements in there and hit those. Given the 2 things I had to do (the ini_set and $dispatcher), should I be able to define those in bootstrap like they are defined in their respective files as you explain? Regardless, I'm happy with the results!